# How do I use pyodbc to export the SQL code of all the views in a Microsoft Access database?

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to use **pyodbc** to export the SQL code of all the **views** in a Microsoft Access database. I am using the code below to access all the table names and types, but I cannot figure out how to access the SQL code behind these views. I have searched online extensively and looked through the pyodbc documentation, but I cannot find any explanation of how to do this. Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

db_path = 'path_to_database.accdb'

# Create connection to database
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    + 'DBQ={};Trusted_Connection=yes;'.format(db_path))

# Print the table types and names
with conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for row in cursor.tables():
        print(row.table_type, row.table_name)
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Example output:

```
SYNONYM Group List
...
SYSTEM TABLE MSysObjects
SYSTEM TABLE MSysQueries
...
TABLE Classification List
TABLE Financial_2022
VIEW All Programs
VIEW ERROR_Mismatch
VIEW FTEs
VIEW UNION_Cascade
```

I don't know what the MySysQueries system table is, and I have tried to access the information inside of it but I cannot: `Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysQueries.'`

I have seen an [example](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-views/sql-server-get-view-information/) of how to do this in SQL Server, but I do not know how to translate that to pyodbc and Microsoft Access.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the backend ODBC-Access connection does not expose metadata on saved queries in Access outside the MSys* tables. However, you can access the frontend of Access. Consider interfacing to the Access Object Library to access the [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydefs-collection-dao) collection to retrieve all underlying SQL statements.

Python's `win32com` is usually pre-installed for Windows installations of Python. Also, below may work without even having MSAccess installed. You will just need the DAO library (.dll) available.

```py
import win32com.client

try:
    dbe = win32com.client.Dispatch("DAO.DBEngine.120")
    db = dbe.OpenDatabase(r"C:\Path\To\Access\Database.accdb")

    # ITERATE THROUGH ALL SAVED QUERIES
    for qdef in db.QueryDefs():
        print(qdef.Name)
        print(qdef.SQL)
        print()
        
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    
finally:
    # RELEASE RESOURCES
    qdef = None; db = None; dbe = None
    del qdef; del db; del dbe
```